# Is $f(x,y)=(x+2y+y^2+|xy|, 2x+y+x^2+|xy|)$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Define $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ by $$f(x,y)=(x+2y+y^2+|xy|, 2x+y+x^2+|xy|)$$

Now is $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$ and $Df(0,0)$ invertible?

I am having problem with the modulus function. How can I solve this? thanks.

Comment: Could you please tell me the source of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Find corresponding $2\times 2$ matrix. Now note that at $(0,0)$ matrix becomes \begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\
2&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
Since determinant is non-zero so derivative is invertible. I hope this helps.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: how to find the matrix?

Comment: $f(x,y)=(u,v)$, then matrix is\begin{pmatrix}
u_x&u_y\\
v_x&v_y\\
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: don't you think $|xy|$ will create a problem for $(0,0)$?

Comment: No dear. Please try.

Comment: I have tried. Please tell me something derivative of $|xy|$ w.r.t $x$ is $\frac{x|y|}{|x|}$, right?

Comment: Yes. Go ahead please.

Comment: Ok please make me right if am wrong, then at $(0,0)$, isn't $|x|=0$ making the expression undefined?

Comment: No my dear. please not that $x/∣x∣$ is either 1 or -1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33039/discussion-between--prasad-and-quintic).

Comment: I think you got my point right ?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Don't you need to check that the partial derivatives are continuous or some other argument to assert that the total derivative exists?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Denote by $h_x=\rho\cos{\varphi}$ and $h_y=\rho\sin{\varphi}$ increments of $x$ and $y$ respectively. Then the increment of $|xy|$ at $(0,\,0)$ equals
$$|h_x h_y| = \rho^2 |\sin{\varphi}\cos{\varphi}| \leqslant \rho^2 = o(\rho), \;\;\rho \to {0}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We have

$$f(x,y)=(x+2y, 2x+y) +(y^2+|xy|,+x^2+|xy|).$$

Now $(x+2y, 2x+y)$ is linear and the rest of it isn't. If this has any chance at all, the latter term must satisfy the $o(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})$ condition. Does it? If not, we're done. If yes, then $Df(0,0)$ is the linear term and you need to determine if it is invertible.

Comment: I didn't understand it properly. Can you explain it bit more clearly? Answer says it it differentiable and $Df$ is invertible at $(0,0)$.