# Is $f$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ given by $$f(x,y)=(3x+2y+y^2+|xy|,2x+3y+x^2+|xy|)$$ Is it differentiable at (0,0)?

I considered this as $f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$ and checked that both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable, is it okay?

Comment: Yes it is. In fact the derivative is  invertible. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533832/is-fx-y-x2yy2xy-2xyx2xy-differentiable?rq=1

Comment: @Tanuj yes I took it, so the options will be 3,4 right?

Comment: Don't remember the options.Don't have the QP with me. It is differentiable at (0,0)